# Dynamic SVG: Why is the interactivity (javascript) not working?

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to create a bar chart as a dynamic SVG, where an explanatory text pops up when I hover over a bar. The SVG was created in Adobe Illustrator, I am now trying to add interactivity. This SVG is not meant to be embedded in further HTML code. I am opening the SVG file in Chrome, if that is important.

Everything works fine (e.g. changing color when hovering), except the javascript functionality (pop up text) and I just can't figure out why.

This ist my code:

```
<svg id="iamsvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
  <defs>
  <style>
.zahlen {
  font-family:OpenSans-Regular, "Open Sans";
  font-size:50px;
  stroke:#000000;
  fill:#000000;
}

.balken {
  stroke-width:.5px;
  stroke:#5e5eee;
  fill:#5e5eee;
}

.balken:hover {
  stroke:#e70e7e;
  fill:#e70e7e;
}

.linien {
  stroke:#aeb6e5;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
  fill:none;
}

#mypopup {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#mypopup::before {
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -6px;
  top: 68px;
}
      </style>
</defs><g>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="1020.62" x2="1858.99" y2="1020.62"/>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="1020.62" x2="186.58" y2="998.37"/></g>
  <g><g>
    <text class="zahlen" transform="translate(17.5 901.7)"><tspan x="0" y="0">10000</tspan></text>
    <text class="zahlen" transform="translate(17.5 753.37)"><tspan x="0" y="0">20000</tspan></text>
    <text class="zahlen" transform="translate(17.5 605.05)"><tspan x="0" y="0">30000</tspan></text>
    <text class="zahlen" transform="translate(17.5 456.72)"><tspan x="0" y="0">40000</tspan></text>
    <text class="zahlen" transform="translate(17.5 308.39)"><tspan x="0" y="0">50000</tspan></text>
    <text class="zahlen" transform="translate(17.5 160.07)"><tspan x="0" y="0">60000</tspan></text>
    </g>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="1020.62" x2="186.58" y2="130.67"/><g>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="1020.62" x2="228.39" y2="1020.62"/>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="872.3" x2="1859.24" y2="872.3"/>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="723.97" x2="1859.24" y2="723.97"/>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="575.65" x2="1859.24" y2="575.65"/>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="427.32" x2="1859.24" y2="427.32"/>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="279" x2="1859.24" y2="279"/>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="130.67" x2="1859.24" y2="130.67"/></g></g>
 <g id="myicon" pointer-events="all"> 
    <rect class="balken" x="201.21" y="572.25" width="75.26" height="448.37"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="305.74" y="350.95" width="75.26" height="669.67"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="410.26" y="834" width="75.26" height="186.62"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="514.79" y="901.44" width="75.26" height="119.18"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="619.31" y="982.58" width="75.26" height="38.05"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="723.84" y="919.9" width="75.26" height="100.73"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="828.37" y="766.11" width="75.26" height="254.51"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="932.89" y="951.99" width="75.26" height="68.63"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1037.42" y="603.16" width="75.26" height="417.46"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1141.95" y="214.64" width="75.26" height="805.98"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1246.47" y="839.68" width="75.26" height="180.94"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1351" y="973.31" width="75.26" height="47.32"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1455.52" y="852.61" width="75.26" height="168.01"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1560.05" y="920.3" width="75.26" height="100.33"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1664.58" y="859.22" width="75.26" height="161.41"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1769.1" y="946.4" width="75.26" height="74.22"/>
    </g>
    <!--HOVERTEXT-->
    <div id="mypopup">
    <h3>Popup title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <script type="application/javascript">
      <![CDATA[
        var myicon = document.getElementById("myicon");
        var mypopup = document.getElementById("mypopup");

        myicon.addEventListener("mouseover", showPopup);
        myicon.addEventListener("mouseout", hidePopup);

        function showPopup(evt) {
        var iconPos = myicon.getBoundingClientRect();
        mypopup.style.left = (iconPos.right + 20) + "px";
        mypopup.style.top = (window.scrollY + iconPos.top - 60) + "px";
        mypopup.style.display = "block";
        }

        function hidePopup(evt) {
          mypopup.style.display = "none";
        }
       ]]>
    </script> 
    </svg>
```

I am very grateful for any help!

Comment: There are a lot of elements inside the SVG that don't belong there, such as html tags like h3, div and p. Also, elements inside an svg cannot have :before pseudo elements as in your styles. Your svg needs to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are pretty close. You have to leave out the HTML. Here , I replaced the HTML element with a `<g>` element and an orange rectangle.

So this would be the content of the SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="iamsvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .zahlen {
        font-family:OpenSans-Regular, "Open Sans";
        font-size:50px;
        stroke:#000000;
        fill:#000000;
      }

      .balken {
        stroke-width:.5px;
        stroke:#5e5eee;
        fill:#5e5eee;
      }

      .balken:hover {
        stroke:#e70e7e;
        fill:#e70e7e;
      }

      .linien {
        stroke:#aeb6e5;
        stroke-miterlimit:10;
        fill:none;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="1020.62" x2="1858.99" y2="1020.62"/>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="1020.62" x2="186.58" y2="998.37"/>
  </g>
  <g>
    <g>
      <text class="zahlen" transform="translate(17.5 901.7)"><tspan x="0" y="0">10000</tspan></text>
      <text class="zahlen" transform="translate(17.5 753.37)"><tspan x="0" y="0">20000</tspan></text>
      <text class="zahlen" transform="translate(17.5 605.05)"><tspan x="0" y="0">30000</tspan></text>
      <text class="zahlen" transform="translate(17.5 456.72)"><tspan x="0" y="0">40000</tspan></text>
      <text class="zahlen" transform="translate(17.5 308.39)"><tspan x="0" y="0">50000</tspan></text>
      <text class="zahlen" transform="translate(17.5 160.07)"><tspan x="0" y="0">60000</tspan></text>
    </g>
    <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="1020.62" x2="186.58" y2="130.67"/>
    <g>
      <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="1020.62" x2="228.39" y2="1020.62"/>
      <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="872.3" x2="1859.24" y2="872.3"/>
      <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="723.97" x2="1859.24" y2="723.97"/>
      <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="575.65" x2="1859.24" y2="575.65"/>
      <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="427.32" x2="1859.24" y2="427.32"/>
      <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="279" x2="1859.24" y2="279"/>
      <line class="linien" x1="186.58" y1="130.67" x2="1859.24" y2="130.67"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="myicon" pointer-events="all"> 
    <rect class="balken" x="201.21" y="572.25" width="75.26" height="448.37"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="305.74" y="350.95" width="75.26" height="669.67"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="410.26" y="834" width="75.26" height="186.62"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="514.79" y="901.44" width="75.26" height="119.18"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="619.31" y="982.58" width="75.26" height="38.05"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="723.84" y="919.9" width="75.26" height="100.73"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="828.37" y="766.11" width="75.26" height="254.51"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="932.89" y="951.99" width="75.26" height="68.63"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1037.42" y="603.16" width="75.26" height="417.46"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1141.95" y="214.64" width="75.26" height="805.98"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1246.47" y="839.68" width="75.26" height="180.94"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1351" y="973.31" width="75.26" height="47.32"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1455.52" y="852.61" width="75.26" height="168.01"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1560.05" y="920.3" width="75.26" height="100.33"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1664.58" y="859.22" width="75.26" height="161.41"/>
    <rect class="balken" x="1769.1" y="946.4" width="75.26" height="74.22"/>
  </g>
  <g id="mypopup" pointer-events="none" visibility="hidden">
    <rect width="300" height="200" fill="orange"/>
  </g>
  <script>
    <![CDATA[
      var myicon = document.getElementById("myicon");
      var mypopup = document.getElementById("mypopup");

      myicon.addEventListener("mouseover", showPopup);
      myicon.addEventListener("mouseout", hidePopup);

      function showPopup(evt) {
        var iconPos = evt.target.getBBox();
        let top = (iconPos.y+300 > 1080) ? iconPos.y - 200 : iconPos.y-35;
        let left = (iconPos.x+400 > 1920) ? 1920 - 400 : iconPos.x+35;
        mypopup.setAttribute('transform', 'translate('+left+' '+top+')');
        mypopup.style.visibility = "visible";
      }

      function hidePopup(evt) {
        mypopup.style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
    ]]>
  </script> 
</svg>
```

And here is an example of the exact same file as data URI used in an object elements. So, it is like just displaying the content of the SVG file in a browser:

```html
<object data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"></object>
```